# How to use JSDoc annotations in indexed types

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I have a `Tables` type with the nested indexed properties. And I want to indicate what context the object is but JsDoc is not indicating my comments. How do I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
type Tables = {
    /**
     * Table name
     */
    [tableName: string]: {
      /**
       * Column name
       */
      [columnName: string]: Properties
    }
  }
```

I don't know if this is related to my IDE but I was expecting to see the annotation on the tooltip:

[image: ts indexed property comment]

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: That's helpful, but saying **in text** what you're looking for and not seeing would be more helpful. Not everyone cal see the images, or understand what it is about the image contents that you find lacking.

Comment: I think it's just not something that the IDE offers. You can put a doc comment on the type explaining what it is, though, so that at least that information is available if they hover the type name.

Comment: yeah the doc comments are appearing on hover but not in indexed types, i wonder if i do wrong

Comment: I don't think so, FWIW. :-)

Comment: maybe i shouldn't even ask here, silly question :)

Comment: Perfectly valid question IMHO. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```js
type Tables = {
  [
    /**
     * Table name
     */
    tableName: string
  ]: {
    [
      /**
       * Column name
       */
      columnName: string
    ]: string
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]